Systemd reports "failed to start Raise Network interfaces even though the network is connected and functioning
I have an Ubuntu server, which started life as a 16.04, which has been upgraded to 20.04 and, in the last week, 22.04. Been in service for a number of years, and has been migrated from an MSI maniboard running an AMD Sempron to a Gigabyte manboard running an i3. It was originally running with a static IP and providing DHCP/DNS services (dnsmasq) to the rest of my network.
As well as upgrading the installed version of Ubuntu server, I changed the system back to dynamic, getting its IP address from a new Fritzbox router. Generally, things are working, but I've a couple of errors that worry me a bit.
Main one is that during boot, I get the following error:
Jul 31 16:46:18 tarus systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 31 16:46:18 tarus systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.

The network is fully functional, but Cockpit is also reporting a network failure. In addition, looking through the journal, I'm seeing strings of avahi error warnings:
Aug 03 16:34:45 tarus avahi-daemon[1008]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.254 on enp7s0.IPv4.
Aug 03 16:34:45 tarus avahi-daemon[1008]: iface.c: avahi_server_add_address() failed: Not supported

I've no idea where to start tracing these two, would be grateful for any suggestions.
I have noticed that the upgrade process has not touched the network control, which is still as it was in 16.04, not migrated to netplan.
If it is of interest, I fixed the "Failed to start Raise network interfaces", once I discovered that for some reason, the "consistently" named interface name had been changed during the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. No idea why, and didn't think to check that when I first found the problem. Very odd. Changing /etc/network/interfaces to the new name fixed it. Also seems to have fixed the constant avahi complaints about the IPV6 address.
